# Does NetSuite load custom sublists when a record is being printed through freemarker / advanced pdf templates?

Tags: freemarker, netsuite

I am a NetSuite newbie, so I apologize in advance if this has a simple answer that I do not see.

We have a custom record type that among other things, has a field indicating the list/record (invoice or credit memo) that a particular custom record is related to. Using this, I have a saved search sublist on the invoice record.

When this invoice is being printed / emailed using an advanced template, I can't seem to be able to find this sublist using freemarker syntax (I can access the normal item sublist just fine). I have also tried to make this custom record type a child / parent relationship with the invoice, but i get the same result.

Based on this [SuiteAnswer](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/40475/kw/sublist%20freemarker) and the [NS help article](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/32621/kw/scriptable%20template) on freemarker, it looks like it is possible.

When I load an invoice record in the UI and append &xml=t to the URL, I can see the normal items sublist, but I do not see any other sublist available.

Is there something I need to do to make a custom sublist exposed to the template engine?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to find the internal id of the sublist. Right click on the title of the sublist and select 'Inspect Element'. You'll notice a repeated string in the html similar to `customsublist1`.

Once you have that you should be able to access the line items using normal Freemarker sequence syntax.

```
<#list record.customsublist1 as item>
  ${item.field1}
<#/list>
```